# Two different comparisons ("more ... than" and "same ... as") in one sentence

Tags: sentence, comparisons

Consider two tasks named A and B with the following properties:

- Task A requires **more** effort **than** task B.
- Task A yields **as much** reward **as** task B.

I want to say both statements in one sentence. Which of the following are correct? Which one's the best?

1. Task A requires more effort than task B and yields the same reward as task B.
2. Task A requires more effort than and yields the same reward as task B.
3. Task A requires more effort and yields the same reward as task B.

Basically I want to avoid 1. and I am not sure whether 2. or 3. are correct, if any.

Comment: Actually, #1 is clearest. I'd go with "Task A requires more effort than task B but yields the same reward." #2 is good. #3 is not precise, but still understandable.

Comment: My personal take would be "Task A yields the same reward as Task B but requires more effort."

Comment: Note that _but_ is more natural than _and_ between clauses; they do contrast, after all. (3) is mildly ungrammatical (since _than_ and _as_ aren't exactly identical) but most people will ignore it in speech, or even in writing. (2) is safest for writing. (1) is unnecessarily complete, a mark of emphasis, and raises a question about what's being emphasized here.